# analysing a numerical method

Tags: numerical-methods

I am learning numerical methods and even though I read several articles I still could not have a summarized idea of how and what exactly the following means.

What is the idea/definition of accuracy, stability, consistency and convergence of a numerical method? What relationship do they have with others?

I know that the stability and consistency imply convergence. Does this mean, if a method is convergent that it is stable and consistent?

Do the accuracy and convergence imply similar ideas?

I know these questions sounds very basic but I appreciate if someone can help me to sort them out or recommend a clear article/book that I can refer to.

Comment: Convergence usually refers to how fast the algorithm gets to the solution. Accuracy means how close to the real solution you get. Stability means that if one starts with slightly different initial conditions will get to the same answer (within accuracy).